# Can't write H264 videos with Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

Using OpenCV with Python 3.6 (within an Anaconda platform) in a Windows environment, I can write videos using the DIVX, MJPG, and MPEG codecs (and probably some others) but cannot write videos using the H264 codec.  I can read AVC1 (which is a version of H264) videos with OpenCV without issue.

I have `opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll` in my `Anaconda3` folder and also in my `Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` folder.  I have also placed the downloaded and unzipped version of ffmpeg in my main (C:) folder.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what I need to do to write H264 videos with OpenCV?  Thanks!

Comment: you'll have to compile opencv with h264 encoder support

Comment: @Micka Not opencv, compile ffmpeg with h264 support.